# PHP parse date column from excel sheet (CSV)

Tags: php, excel, csv, date, strtotime

I created CSV file having date field in format 12-08-2018. When I opened csv file in Excel sheet it displays and saves in format 12/AUG/2018 to file.

When I am trying to parse it gives me wrong:

```
<?php
     echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('12/AUG/2018')); // 1969-12-31
?>
```

So, What could be the best way to handle parsing of date coming form excel sheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) function

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y', '12/AUG/2018');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d'); // 2018-08-12
```

Comment: Thanks @splash58 for quick response. If I use DateTime::createFromFormat(), It means, I should be knowing what formats are expected from excel sheet. Because data coming from excel sheet can be in different formats. So, Should I be handling all cases? Isn't there a solution like automatic format detection and parsing ?

Comment: Only some fixed formats can be recognized by datetime functions.  In other cases you should try all possible formats

Comment: how will we detect what is format of date coming in ? To pass it further on.

Comment: if you know the set of formats, try them while datetime fails

Comment: For e.g.
After failure of datetime, one format I find 12/AUG/2018, Another format I find 12.AUG.2018, So how will I decide which format to be used ?

Comment: this is beautiful.